# Выбор элементов с первого по заданный

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В данном коде

```
$(".onepage-pagination li a" + ".active").removeClass("active");
$(".onepage-pagination li a" + "[data-index='" + (page_index) + "']").addClass("active");
```

добавляется класс `active` кнопкам текущей страницы. Мне нужно, чтобы класс `active` добавлялся всем кнопкам с первой по текущую.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, вы хотите отмечать активным кнопки с атрибутом `data-index`, значение которого меньше или равно `page_index`, да?

```js
var page_index = 4;

$(".onepage-pagination li a").removeClass("active").each(function() {
    if (+$(this).attr("data-index") <= page_index) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="onepage-pagination">
    <li><a href="#" data-index="1">1</a>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="2">2</a>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="3">3</a>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="4">4</a>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="5">5</a>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="6" class="active">6</a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, можно сделать проще. И старайтесь, особенно в больших проектах, использовать меньше условных операторов.

```
var page_index = 4;

$(".onepage-pagination li a").removeClass("active");
$(".onepage-pagination li a:lt("+page_index+")").addClass("active");
});
```

Или ещё удобнее и проще вариант с методом `.slice()`:

```
var page_index = 4,
       items_pag = $(".onepage-pagination li a");

items_pag.removeClass("active");
items_pag.slice(0,page_index).addClass("active");
});
```